# Eigenvalue problem for integral equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, improper-integrals, integral-equations, eigenfunctions, characteristics

We need to solve the eigenvalue problem for the integral operator
$$
\frac1{1-x}\int_0^{+\infty} K\left(\frac{x}{t}\right) u(t)dt = \lambda u(x).
$$
We assume that integral kernel $K$ is analytic and decays sufficiently fast at $+\infty$. I tried to construct a differential equation for $u$ as follows. First, I consider more general case
$$
\frac1{1-x}\int_0^{+\infty} K\left(\frac{xa}{t}\right) u(t)dt = \lambda u(x),
$$
now $u=u(x,a)$. Then I differentiated this equation in $x$ and in $a$, replacing the integral by $(1-x)\lambda u$:
$$
(1-x)^{-1}\lambda u + (1-x)^{-1}\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{a}{t} K'\left(\frac{xa}{t}\right) u(t)dt = \lambda u_x;
$$
$$
(1-x)^{-1}\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x}{t} K'\left(\frac{xa}{t}\right) u(t)dt = \lambda u_a.
$$
From the last two equations, we obtain
$$
(1-x)^{-1} u + \frac{a}{x} u_a = u_x.
$$
Thus, $xu_x-au_a=\frac{x}{1-x} u$. Then we introduce function $v$ such that $u=v e^{\int\frac{x}{1-x} dx}$, and
we obtain for $v(x,a)$ the following equation
$$
xv_x-av_a=0.
$$
I use the method of characteristics but failed because I do not know "initial" starting values.
Maybe I should change the approach in the very beginning?

Answer (score 1):

$$x\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}-a\frac{\partial v}{\partial a}=0$$
Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs :
$$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{da}{-a}=\frac{dv}{0}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from $dv=0$
$$v=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from $\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{da}{-a}$
$$xa=c_2$$
General solution of the PDE on the form of implicit equation $c_1=F(c_2)$
$$v(x,a)=F(xa)$$
$F$ is an arbitray function.
$$u=ve^{\int\frac{x}{1-x}dx}=\frac{e^{-x}}{1-x}F(xa)$$

Comment: Thank you very much, @JJacquelin. Thus, the solution at $a=1$ is $u(x)=\frac{e^{-x}}{1-x}F(x)$. The next step is to find function $F$, depending on integral kernel $K$. I inserted $K(z)=e^{-z}$ but could not proceed further.